# anonymous nested struct usage

Tags: go

I've asked this question before and deleted it. but I don't understand. I tried everything but still getting error. how can i use this struct. or am i doing it wrong

```
type Unit struct{
    category struct{
        name string
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you followed our advice on your deleted questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the following:

```golang
var unit = Unit{
    category: {
        name: "foo",
    },
}
```

will NOT work because the language specification says that you MUST **specify the type** when initializing a struct's field with a composite literal value. E.g. a nested struct, or a map, or a slice, etc.

---

Since `category`'s type is an unnamed composite type, to initialize the field you MUST repeat the unnamed composite type's definition.

```golang
type Unit struct{
    category struct{
        name string
    }
}

var unit = Unit{
    category: struct{
        name string
    }{
        name: "foo",
    },
}
```

Alternative, do not use anonymous structs.

```golang
type Category struct {
    name string
}

type Unit struct{
    category Category
}

var unit = Unit{
    category: Category{
        name: "foo",
    },
}
```

And if you want to use this struct outside of the package in which it is declared you MUST export its fields

```golang
type Category struct {
    Name string
}

type Unit struct{
    Category Category
}

// ...

var unit = mypkg.Unit{
    Category: mypkg.Category{
        Name: "foo",
    },
}
```